# serve symfony 5 project to host machine from VMware

Tags: php, apache, vmware, symfony5

On my VMWARE running debian 10 I started a new project using:

`composer create-project symfony/wesite-skeleton myproject`

I served it using:

`php -S 0.0.0.0:8987 -t public`

And it worked

Trying to kickoff with the framework i created a controller and wanted to return some HTML

Now my project won't load and instead it sends

`An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver`

I think it has to do with the php server and tried to look into how to serve using apache:
I tried using the apache-pack and didn't find the `.htaccess` file
Some more research and i understood that apache only serves through /var/www/html

Yet I want to serve my symfony 5 project from my VMWARE debian 5 to my Windows 10 through the VM `ip`
and a persnalised port.
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is kind of clear but i think the lack of documentation has to do with how hard it is to solve it.

- The php server is enough
- In the .env file one HAS to setup the MySQL database using his username & password
- Make sure you can login to your MySQL -and have a database set for your project- using a username other than root and grant that user all priviliges "Must be able to login to `msql -u <user> -p` without sudo.
- Additional step and i don't know if everyone has to do so: in `/etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini`
  at a line where there is a line `;extension=pdo_mysql` you decomment this line -delete the `;` and change it to `extension=pdo_mysql.so` to avoid the PDO driver not found Exception

hope this helps future users